# Flask-sqlalchemy check constraint - value of one column cannot be the same as any value on another column?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Sensor(db.Model):

    __table_args__ = (
        db.CheckConstraint('dat_pin != clk_pin', name='Data Pin != Clock Pin'),
    )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name  = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False,)
    dat_pin  = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False,)
    clk_pin  = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False,)
    zero_val  = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True,)
    cal_factor  = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True,)
    full_val  = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True,)
    alert_val  = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True,)
    values = db.relationship('SensorValues', backref='author', lazy=True) #not a column in table, just backreference


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Sensor('{self.name}', '{self.dat_pin}', '{self.clk_pin}', '{self.zero_val}', '{self.cal_factor}', '{self.full_val}', '{self.alert_val}')"
```

I need to set a constraint so that dat_pin or clock_pin can never be the same as any other dat_pin or clk_pin in the table. I tried to add a table-wide constraint but that only seems to check the row I'm trying to add. I need it to also check any previous records, for example:

```
DAT_PIN CLK_PIN
1       2       = OK (Because both are different from each other and different from any other dat_pin or clock_pin records)
DAT_PIN CLK_PIN
3       3       = NOT OK (This is how it works currently)
DAT_PIN CLK_PIN
4       1       = NOT OK (Because the first record has dat_pin=1)
DAT_PIN CLK_PIN
2       5       = ALSO NOT OK (Because clk_pin has already been 2)
```

I hope the example was clear enough, I'm having trouble defining this constraint in a short sentence, english is not my first language. Also I need the rest of the columns to be unconstrained, so that full_val for example can still have the same value as any dat_pin or clk_pin.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead store the relationship between sensors and pins in another table, and have a discriminator field for each record specifying the type of pin, then you can use the pin's number as a primary key which will enforce the uniqueness of the number across the two types of pin. We can also use the inbuilt sqlalchemy inheritance patterns to automate the setting of the discriminator fields and let us use nice descriptive class names for each type of pin.

Perhaps just best to let the code do the talking:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Sensor(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False,)
    dat_pin = db.relationship(
        "Pin",
        primaryjoin="and_(Sensor.id==Pin.sensor_id, Pin.type=='dat')",
        uselist=False,
    )
    clk_pin = db.relationship(
        "Pin",
        primaryjoin="and_(Sensor.id==Pin.sensor_id, Pin.type=='clk')",
        uselist=False,
    )


class Pin(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.Enum("dat", "clk"), nullable=False)
    sensor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("sensor.id"))

    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint("type", "sensor_id"),)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type}


class DatPin(Pin):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "dat"}


class ClkPin(Pin):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "clk"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # proof of concept
    with app.test_request_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        sensor = Sensor(name="sensor")
        db.session.add(sensor)
        db.session.commit()
        sensor.dat_pin = DatPin(id=1)
        sensor.clk_pin = ClkPin(id=2)
        db.session.commit()
        print(sensor.dat_pin, sensor.clk_pin)

    # add dat_pin with id=1 to a sensor,
    # and then a clk_pin with id=1 to another sensor
    with app.test_request_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        sensor1 = Sensor(name="sensor1")
        sensor2 = Sensor(name="sensor2")
        db.session.add_all([sensor1, sensor2])
        db.session.commit()
        sensor1.dat_pin = DatPin(id=1)
        sensor2.clk_pin = ClkPin(id=1)
        # will raise integrity error due to multiple primary keys
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Yep, raised %s", e)
            db.session.rollback()

    # test to prove only one type of each pin allowed per sensor
    with app.test_request_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        db.session.add(Sensor(name="sensor", id=1))
        db.session.add_all([ClkPin(sensor_id=1), ClkPin(sensor_id=1)])
        # will raise integrity error due to violation of unique constraint
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Yep, raised %s", e)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.

I'd prefer to keep it in one table since changing the database structure would require me rewriting all the queries. However, say I would make another relationship table, wouldn't it be easier to just set a table-wide unique constraint for dat_pin and clk_pin? I mean, assuming I've understood table-wide constraints correctly, wouldn't that mean that no column of any record can have identical values? Or would that constraint interfere with keys? F.ex if id=1, dat_pin cannot be 1?

Comment: A unique constraint on (dat_pin, clk_pin) would allow (1,2) and (2,1), which you are trying to avoid if I understand your original question. Although, I’m not sure if that’s what you are referring to when you say “table-wide” constraint, it’s not a term I’m familiar with. If you mean a single constraint that ensures no field in any column can have a value equivalent to any other field in any other column, I’ve not come across a constraint like that, in which case, feel free to take this answer as a comment.